# What are "Versions" in Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Given the [introduction to unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unit-testing/570/introduction-to-unit-testing#t=201607211101434995704), I see a topic "Versions" which is

```
| Version | Release Date |
| ------- | ------------ |
| C       | 2016-04-20   |
| C++     | 2016-04-20   |
| C#      | 2016-04-20   |
| Java    | 2016-04-20   |
| VB      | 2016-04-20   |
```

What is that supposed to mean?

- Can I view examples for specific programming languages? (If so, I didn't find the link)
- Does the example work in these programming languages? (I doubt because of the `var` keyword)
- Nothing? (The way way versions is used here is wrong)

Comment: Looks to me like that that is just another garbage documentation post that is either super low quality, or misplaced somewhere where it barely makes sense. No clue why there is a version table for something that does not have a version

Comment: i raised a concern about unit testing in chat in the pre beta beta chat room.

Answer (score 7):

The quick-edit help (the [yellow window in the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWNed.png)) provides the following documentation (ha) for that feature:

> #### Editing Versions
>
> This section controls the versions that may be added to the topics in
>   this tag.
>
> Only list versions that see significant real world use. Pre-releases,
>   release candidates, alpha/beta versions, and so on only serve to
>   clutter the topics they're applied to.
>
> Only remove versions that shouldn't have been documented in the first
>   place. Removing versions from this section also removes them from all
>   topics they are attached to.
>
> Linking to release notes is encouraged.
>
> Versions must be formatted as a table, where the first column is the
>   version name and the last column is a YYYY-MM-DD style release date.

The versions feature is [described on a help-page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-versions):

> #### Flexible Versions
>
> Each tag with documentation can have versions associated with it. These are listed as tables on a tags root topic, separated by headings if there is more than one relevant “family” of versions.

What are they for? Well, you can link to the "real" documentation. For example, if you want to document `ACME.RocketLauncher.Start()`, which has been introduced in T.NET version 2.3, you can link to T.NET's documentation:

```
Version | Release Date  
--      | --
[2.3]   | 1452-12-6
[2.4]   | 1552-12-6
[2.5]   | 1652-12-6
[3.0]   | 2022-12-19

  [2.3]: http://example.com/tnet/v-2.3/old/acme/rocketlauncher#start
  [2.4]: http://example.com/tnet/v-2.4/old/acme/rocketlauncher#start
  [2.5]: http://example.com/tnet/v-2.5/acme/rocketlauncher#start
  [3.0]: http://example.com/tnet/prime-3.0/acme/rocketlauncher#start
```

However, as far as I've seen from several topics, that feature is currently not used correctly. For example your linked post  just added the [date of the SO documentation page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/unit-testing/revisions/570) and all languages where the content is applicable.

Comment: "quick-edit help" where in the world is this? The tour? A glowing blue circle? Help center?

Comment: @Braiam It shows up when you edit something. Maybe that's not the correct term. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWNed.png