# Versions section in arbitrary subject really horrible UX

Tags: discussion, documentation

I was complexly confused by where the versions I kept seeing everywhere were defined, as there was no obvious top level "Control Page" where those would emanate from.

If versions are a central concept to the design, hiding them in some random page that is practically indifferent from all the other subjects is confusing to say the least.

In fact, I had seen that page, and that version list, and not realised that's what its purpose was.

It wasn't until I stumbled onto [What are "Versions" in Documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328425/what-are-versions-in-documentation) that I realised it was hidden in some page somewhere.

In essence, this feature is *buried* in the user interface where one will not find it via intuition.

Even this documentation https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-versions doesn't really make that obvious, and I wouldn't have found that documentation without the above mentioned question, because nothing I did pushed me in that direction.

I only had blind "Here's a list of versions, pick the ones that apply" options.

Things make way more sense retroactively, but they're still muddy as hell.